# Can't access dom elements in durandal

Tags: jquery, html, durandal

This is a mobile app running durandal
In my html page i have names and images.
The following function formats my page:

```
define(function (){
function getAutors(myUrl) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: myUrl,
            data: { numAuthors: 23 },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: processArray,
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                alert("Não conseguimos aceder aos dados");
            }


function processArray(arr) {
   var out = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out +='<div class="col-xs-12 text-center"> <a class="autor" style="color:black" id="' + arr[i].id + '" data-bind=" event  {click : btnClick}" ><h4>' +
        arr[i].name + '</h4></a></div>';
    } 
    $("#aqui").html(out)


}
return{
           activate: function(){},
           compositionComplete(){
               getAutors(this.myUrl);},
           btnClick: function(){
                  alert('You have clicked this');
           }
         };
    });
})
```

My btnClick function doesn't activate when i click any of the authors names
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please show the view

Answer (score 0):

Your btnClick will never be called, because you are creating HTML after the page is binded. You are making a AJAX request, and if this request doenst fail, it will call your **processArray** method, and then it will create DOM element in your page, but in this time, Durandal already ran **applyBindings** and this new DOM with data-bind attributes, will not work.
When you are using Knockout, you must avoid use element manipulation with jQuery, you must use MVVM way.

To do that, you should use out-of-the-box template engine that knockout have, and use **foreach** databind to loop through your observableArray and then create desired html DOM, here follow the modification of your code, using foreach databind and observableArray:

```
define(function (){
    var vm = {
        authors: ko.observableArray(),
        getAutors: function (myUrl) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: myUrl,
                data: { numAuthors: 23 },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: processArray,
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    alert("Não conseguimos aceder aos dados");
                }
            });
        },
        processArray: function (arr) {
            this.authors(arr);
        },
        activate: function() { 
            getAutors(this.myUrl);  
        },
        btnClick: function(){
            alert('You have clicked this');
        }
    };

    return vm;
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="aqui" data-bind="foreach: authors">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <a class="autor" style="color:black" data-bind="event {click: $root.btnClick}, attr: {id: id}" >
            <h4></h4>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```